# Mastercard Hosted Checkout Integration always "Payment Unsuccessful" at the end with no error info

Tags: mastercard

I am implementing Mastercard's Hosted Checkout Integration. Detail see below.
https://ap.gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

For checkout.js, I am using interaction.operation: "PURCHASE"

```
Checkout.configure({
      merchant: <xxxx>,
      order: {
        amount: xxxx,
        currency: "AUD",
        description:<xxxxx>,
        id: <my own order id, unique>,
      },
      session: {
        id: <i can successfully get the session id>,
      },
  
      interaction: {
        merchant: {
          name: <xxxx>,
          logo:logo_url_secure
        },
        operation: "PURCHASE",
        displayControl: {
          billingAddress: "HIDE",
          
        },       
      },
    });
    Checkout.showLightbox();
```

The checkout light box can load etc. with no problem. Filled in the test card info.
The "ACS Emulator" shows up as normal. see screenshot below.

[image]

After click on "Submit" on the "ACS Emulator" page, it always gives a "Payment Unsuccessful" result with no error msg etc. See below

[image]

checked the API call to the bank,
https://xxxxxxxxxx.ap.gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/api/performPayment/SESSIONxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?charset=UTF-8
the response is 200, but not successful.

```
{
   "merchantReturnUrl":false,
   "success":false,
   "threeDsRequired":false,
   "alreadySuccessfullyProcessed":false,
   "sessionId":"SESSIONxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "receiptUrl":"/checkout/receipt/SESSIONxxxxxxxx",
   "receiptData":{
      "paymentMethod":null,
      "paymentDetail1":null,
      "orderDate":"4/09/21 7:34 PM"
   },
   "transactionId":"2"
}
```

Anything I did wrong here?

I suspect my test account might not been setup properly?

Any hints are very much appreciated?

Comment: Any solution to this issue ?

Comment: Same problem, 2022...test cards and live cards not working, no hint as to why

Comment: hi do you mind helping me out Checkout.showLightbox() is not working but Checkout.showPaymentPage() is working why is that? Also, why are you using checkout.js when in docs its checkout.min.js?